# Running function with output in a loop in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to output a tail of elements of a list using `tail()` function, with no luck. Here's the code (below). Could someone please help in explaining why no output is being given?

```
for (i in 1:10) {
   tail(list[[i]]
}
```

I'm an R noob, so it's probably a very silly mistake, but I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: Could you show some of the data?

Comment: if you want to see the tail, use `print(tail(list[[i]]))` but this will only work if list is a list of lists, vectors or data frames. If it is a list of strings or scalars, then there would not be a tail at i, just `list[[i]]`

Comment: `list[[i]]` doesn't make sense in this toy example...I think you want `list(i)` maybe?

Comment: @sconfluentus: printing the `tail` did the job. My list is a list of vectors, so yes. Mb putting it as an answer so I can select it?

Comment: Thx all, problem solved :).

Comment: @hummingBird you should look into `lapply` instead of a `for` loop here. It is more concise and idiomatic. And returns a list as opposed to printing, if you later need to do something with the `tail`s.

Comment: @TaylorH honestly, I only needed it for printing the answers. I could've done with manually typing, but I was lazy to do it and it kinda sucked to manually do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate leaving things unanswered. And since no one wanted to post in form of an answer, here it goes:

Thanks to @sconfluentus:

> if you want to see the tail, use `print(tail(list[[i]]))` but this will
>   only work if list is a list of lists, vectors or data frames. If it is
>   a list of strings or scalars, then there would not be a tail at `i`,
>   just `list[[i]]`